# Why softmax cross entropy loss never gives a value of zero in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

Im doing a neural network in tensorflow and Im using softmax_cross_entropy to calculate the loss, I'm doing tests and note that it never gives a value of zero, even if I compare the same values, this is my code

```
labels=[1,0,1,1]


with tf.Session() as sess:
    onehot_labels=tf.one_hot(indices=labels,depth=2)
    logits=[[0.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.],[0.,1.]]
    print(sess.run(onehot_labels))
    loss=tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels,logits=logits)
    print(sess.run(loss))
```

I obtain this

```
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]]
0.31326166
```

Why is not zero??

Comment: Your logits are not right to give a zero loss.

Comment: but why? logits and one hot labels are the same thing ? I don't understand

Comment: No, logits are not the same thing as one hot labels, you apply softmax to the logits and then you get the same as one hot labels.

Comment: the function applies softmax to logits? right? and then compares with one hot labels, and the reason why it is no zero is because when applies the softmax function for example to 1, the result is like 0.7 for example

Comment: The code is correct right? to apply to my neural network and just change logits for the output of my neural network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matias's post is correct. The following code gives the same result as your code

```
labels=[1,0,1,1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    onehot_labels=tf.one_hot(indices=labels,depth=2)
    logits=[[0.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.],[0.,1.]]
    print(sess.run(onehot_labels))

    probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits=logits)
    # cross entropy
    loss = -tf.reduce_sum(onehot_labels * tf.log(probabilities)) / len(labels)

    print(sess.run(loss))
```

Comment: I undestand it , thankyou , my code is correct right? to apply to my neural network and just change logits for the output of my neural network?

Comment: Your code is right. Replace the logits with your network output, and use optimizer to train your network.